# Conversion of dynamic web project in to maven project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, struts2, weblogic-10.x

I have an already working dynamic webproject. When I try to convert it to maven based project it creates problem. When ever accessing a struts2 action its repeating call to the action and got java.lang.stackoverflow error in browser. Any solution please?

Comment: for which method call?

Comment: Struts2 action's execute method call. When I debug it is returning success but Its calling again and again the same method. I am using weblogic 10.0 server and java 1.5 version.

Comment: post MORE informations

Comment: Actually I have a dynamic web project, to build that I use ant tool.Now I want to migrate it in to maven, So I created a pom.xml, build it and deployed it in to the weblogic server. When I access the application home page it is loaded successfully. When I try to access some other page its calling the same action continuously and it results java.lang.stackoverflow error. Don't know how to resolve. please help

Comment: I suggest you use maven archetype and create template for struts2 and copy your stuff.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the problem without any useful information. How this got an upvote escapes me, there's nothing here with which anything can be determined.

Comment: When I convert it to maven I changed some version of the jars. So It created the problem. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Create project with command mvn archetype:generate. Choose the archetype id as
struts2-archetype-starter with archetype number.

Give groupid, archetype id, version and package properly as asked by console.